# Replace string with special char

Tags: php, replace

I have this string: `image/fewe` that I want to replace with something else, but I'm not sure how I'm going to do that, any help maybe?

Comment: Please clarify which string you exactly have (i.e. `image/fewe` or `image/fewe <-` or whatever), what you want to replace, what you want to replace it with and what result you want to get.

Comment: You don't have much detail, so I recommend looking here:<br />
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @draevor its in the title, tag and the help content..

Comment: @draevor The question is tagged with php, also the question title is prefixed with PHP:. So, PHP. (we have to assume)

Comment: Removed irrelevant information.... whether or not your deadline is on Monday does not matter. You should provide *relevant* information, see my first comment. So far, a valid answer to your question could also be `$str = 'foo';` assuming that `$str = 'image/fewe';`. It replaces the string with something else (in this case `foo`).

Comment: Also, show what work you've done and describe exactly where you are having difficulties. Asking for hints is fine; asking for [homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) answers isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str_replace("replace_me", "replace_with", 'image/fewe');

preg_replace() // you'll need to look that up to match your regex with your needs.
```

Not sure what else you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'image/fewe';
$replaceItWith = 'another string';
$result = str_replace('image/fewe', $replaceItWith, $string);
```

If you want to search for patterns in a string, then use `preg_replace()`.